# Can’t instantiate Backbone view a second time

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs

For some reason, I can’t instantiate a view more than once in my Backbone app. I’m given `undefined is not a function`. Why would that be?

**app.coffee**

```
define [
  'views/start'
], (
  StartView
) ->

  initialize = ->   

    # Take us to the start view
    startView = new StartView()
    startView.render() # Works just fine

  initialize: initialize
```

**views/start.coffee**

```
define [
  'jquery'
  'underscore'
  'backbone'
  'text!templates/start.html'
  'views/question'
], (
  $
  _
  Backbone
  StartTemplate
  QuestionView
) ->

  StartView = Backbone.View.extend

    events:
      'click #btn-begin': 'pushQuestionView'

    render: ->

      # Create a template and stuff it into the view element
      @$el.html @template = _.template StartTemplate

      # Inject the HTML in the document
      $('#main').html @el

      # Return view for chaining
      @

    pushQuestionView: ->

      questionView = new QuestionView()
      questionView.render()

  StartView
```

**views/question.coffee**

```
define [
  'jquery'
  'underscore'
  'backbone'
  'text!templates/question.html'
  'views/form'
  'views/start'
], (
  $
  _
  Backbone
  QuestionTemplate
  FormView
  StartView
) ->

  QuestionView = Backbone.View.extend

    events:
      'click #btn-prev': 'goBack'

    render: ->

      # Create a template and stuff it into the view element
      @$el.html @template = _.template QuestionTemplate

      # Inject the HTML in the document
      $('#main').html @$el

      # Return for chaining
      @

    goBack: ->

      console.log StartView # => undefined

      startView = new StartView() # => Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
      startView.render()

  QuestionView
```

Since it worked the first time, it can’t be a syntax error.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console, before getting `Uncaught TypeError:`?

Comment: May be you are refering `question` in `start` and `start` in `question`. That may be the reason for the problem.

Comment: No other errors. I am indeed referring to *question* in *start*, and *start* in *question*. Is that normally a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring `question` in `start` and `start` in `question`. It forms circular dependency. That is the cause for this problem.

From [require.js - circular dependency](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) documentation.

> If you define a circular dependency (a needs b and b needs a), then in
>   this case when b's module function is called, it will get an undefined
>   value for a.

Comment: That doesn’t seem right; the path to the file relative to `main.coffee` is `views/start`. I tried changing it to your suggestion now, and requirejs threw a 404.

Comment: oh. sorry. i think it should be a way up. can you try `../start`

Comment: yes. i'm wrong. it should be `views/start`. you are correct. but you are having some other problem.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I fixed it with `StartView = require('views/start')`. Thanks!